# error going from on activity to another automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I'm using following code, to go from `first` Activity to `ListViewCheckboxes` Activity,  automatically after 5 seconds, but it has following errors:

```
public class first extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstlayout);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // TODO: Your application init goes here.
                Intent mInHome = new Intent(first.this, InvoiceASAPTabActivity.class);
                first.this.startActivity(mInHome);
            first.this.finish();
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

> Error:(17, 33) error: Handler is abstract; cannot be instantiated
>   Error:(21, 57) error: cannot find symbol class InvoiceASAPTabActivity
>   Error:(18, 16) error: cannot find symbol method postDelayed(,int)

I'd really appreciate if someone could help, thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're missing a lot of imports.

Comment: I have these: import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because you imported

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
```

Instead of

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

Comment: thanks but this one still remains :Error:(22, 57) error: cannot find symbol class InvoiceASAPTabActivity

Comment: So I think you are missing the import of InvoiceASAPTabActivity. You should import it. It's like 

`import yourpackagename.InvoiceASAPTabActivity` 

if you're using Android Studio, you can make it manage these things for you. You can go to Preferences --> Editor --> General --> Auto import --> Check Optimize imports on the fly